Query the records to whom Have not been sent an email/sms/Mobile push since last 2years
in our Existing System we have 31M Contacts.
NOw we wanted to Delete The Contacts who did not received any of communication from our end.
like email or sms or mobile push.
And we are trying to query the contacts <= 06/30/2022.
i dont know how to do it with mobile push
but i queried for email, SMS
code is below
> SELECT s.DateUndeliverable as [sub_DateUndeliverable], e.EventDate as [sent_Evdate], sms.ActionDateTime, 

s.SubscriberKey as [sub_subkey],e.SubscriberKey as [sent_subkey],sms.SubscriberKey as [sms_subkey], 

s.SubscriberID,s.Status,s.EmailAddress,s.DateJoined,s.DateUndeliverable, 

s.DateUnsubscribed,s.BounceCount,s.SubscriberType,s.Locale,s.Domain  

FROM _Subscribers s 

LEFT JOIN _Sent e 

    ON s.SubscriberKey = e.SubscriberKey 

    AND e.EventDate  <= '2022/06/30' 

LEFT JOIN _SMSMessageTracking sms 

    ON s.SubscriberKey = sms.SubscriberKey 

    AND sms.ActionDateTime  <= '2022/06/30' 

WHERE e.SubscriberKey IS NULL 

  AND sms.SubscriberKey IS NULL

as per my understanding
_Sent, _SMSMessageTracking will provide the 6 months of data.
Please try to help me the best Approach ASAP and Correct me the Query with email/sms/mobile push
Thank you

I would suggest you run the contacts without channel extract
This will list all contacts who have not been added to a messaging channel

Hi @eazyE
Can you please Brief on this, because iam new to SFMC, SQL.
Please help me out from this :(



also i need to query the Contacts with channels, but not receive any one (email/sms/mobile push) more than 2 years.

please Reply with the approach
